# single soft assertion error is failing subsequent passed scenarios

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, assertion

I am using soft assertion in my test class and getting test data from data provider. Below is the sample code:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "userPages")
public void validatePages(String pageName) {
    try {
        Reporter.log("Logged In User : " + userType, true);
        //Page1 takes extra checks
        if (pageName.equalsIgnoreCase("Page1")) {
            System.out.println("Running in Page1 bloc ");
            softAssert.assertEquals(page.isValidPage1(), true,
                    "Failed to loada : " + pageName);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Running in NON Page1 bloc .. Page Name is :: "+pageName);
            softAssert.assertEquals(page.isValid(), true,
                    "Failed to load : " + pageName);
        }
        softAssert.assertAll();  ---> Appends page1 failures to all the subsequent passed page tests thus marking all of them failed.
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Reporter.log("Test failed for : " + pageName);
    }
    //
}
```

**TestNG** dependency is ::

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>${testng.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

In my case, if a single page fails then all the subsequent pages are marked as failed even if they are passed. I have tried to debug the issue and found that, in  **SoftAssert** class's **assertAll()** method, the error message of previously failed test-data is getting appended

```
public void assertAll() {
if (!m_errors.isEmpty()) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("The following asserts failed:");
  boolean first = true;
  for (Map.Entry<AssertionError, IAssert<?>> ae : m_errors.entrySet()) {
    if (first) {
      first = false;
    } else {
      sb.append(",");
    }
    sb.append("\n\t");
    sb.append(ae.getKey().getMessage());
  }
  throw new AssertionError(sb.toString());
}}
```

This issue is marking false errors in the testNG reports. Please help and advice.

Edit1:

**Data Provider**

```
@DataProvider(name = "userPageNames")
public Object[] creatingObjects() {
    Map<String, String> pagesList = null;
    try {
        pagesList = //Populate Map

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Reporter.log("Failed to get Pages List for " + userType, true);
    }

    Object[] object = new Object[pagesList.keySet().size()];
    Integer i = 0;
    for (String pageName : pagesList.keySet()) {
        object[i] = pageName;
        i++;
    }
    return object;
}
```

**Report:** Genuine Failure

```
Logged In User : user1
Running in Page1 bloc ..
Page verified : Page1

java.lang.AssertionError: The following asserts failed:
Failed to loada : Page1 expected [true] but found [false]
Expected :true
Actual   :false



    at org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert.assertAll(SoftAssert.java:43)
    at web.dishaPages.ValidatePagesTestNew.validatePages(ValidatePagesTestNew.java:88)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper$1.runTestMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.run(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:175)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeHookable(MethodInvocationHelper.java:242)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:576)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:73)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
```

**Report:** Bogus Failures

```
Logged In User : user1
Running in NON Page1 bloc .. Page Name is :: ViewDMPage
Page verified : ViewDMPage

java.lang.AssertionError: The following asserts failed:
Failed to loada : Page1 expected [true] but found [false]
Expected :true
Actual   :false



    at org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert.assertAll(SoftAssert.java:43)
    at web.dishaPages.ValidatePagesTestNew.validatePages(ValidatePagesTestNew.java:88)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper$1.runTestMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.run(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:175)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeHookable(MethodInvocationHelper.java:242)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:576)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:73)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
```

Comment: Can you show us the Data-Provider method and the results of your tests in the Test Report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in your test code.

Your dataprovider powered `@Test` method is basically using one `SoftAssert` instance and then invoking an `assertAll()` for all data provider data set iterations using the same instance.

`SoftAssert` is designed to remember all assertions that have been recorded so far via calls to `assertXXX`.

To fix this problem you should be instantiating the `SoftAssert` object inside the `@Test` method

Answer (score 0):

Re-instantiate your soft assert in `@BeforeMethod` so you do not need to do it in every test method:

```java
public class SoftAssertTest {

    SoftAssert sa;

    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void beforeTest() {
        sa = new SoftAssert();
    }

    @Test
    public void test1 () {
        sa.assertAll();
    }
}
```